# Emacs: pass arguments to inferior Python shell during buffer evaluation

Tags: python, emacs, ide

recently I started using Emacs as a Python IDE, and it not quite intuitive... The problem I am struggling with right now is how to pass command line arguments to the inferior python shell when the buffer is evaluated with C-c C-c. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This doesn't appear to be easily possible; the inferior process managed by the `python.el` module is designed to persist across many invocations of `python-send-buffer` (and friends).  One solution I've found is to write your own function that sets `sys.argv` programmatically from within the inferior process:

```
(defun python-send-buffer-with-my-args (args)
  (interactive "sPython arguments: ")
  (let ((source-buffer (current-buffer)))
    (with-temp-buffer
      (insert "import sys; sys.argv = '''" args "'''.split()\n")
      (insert-buffer-substring source-buffer)
      (python-send-buffer))))
```

Execute this function in your `*scratch*` buffer and/or save it in your `.emacs` file, then, if you want, bind it to a convenient key sequence.  `C-c C-a` doesn't seem to be used by `python-mode`, so perhaps:

```
(global-set-key "\C-c\C-a" 'python-send-buffer-with-my-args)
```

The command will prompt you for arguments to use, then copy your source buffer into a temporary buffer, prepending it with a code snippet that sets `sys.argv` to the list of arguments you supplied, and finally will call `python-send-buffer`.

The above code will just naively split the string you type on whitespace, so if you need to supply arguments that have whitespace in them, you'll need a more sophisticated algorithm.

Comment: Thank you Sean, I got the idea. It does the trick. In this case I can also pass the arguments by directly setting the sys.argv variable before calling the main function.

Comment: if you get this error `progn: Symbol's function definition is void: python-send-buffer` try changing `python-send-buffer` to `python-shell-send-buffer`.