# In emacs how can I execute the currently edited python script with custon arguments?

Tags: python, emacs, ide

I'm using `python.el` for editing python scripts. When I write a script which is later intende as a command line command, I naturaly wat to test the script with sample arguments.

I tried using `C-c C-c` (`python-send-buffer`) to execute the currently edited script and this works perfectly as long as I do not want to pass arguments to the script.

In order to test the script *with* arguments I save at the moment the script ("myscript.py") switch to a shell and run

```
python myscript.py arg1 arg2 arg3
```

Is there a better integrated way to do this? I for sure don't want to modify the script for this test but rsther find a way to call the script with the desired paramters. Obviously `python-send-buffer` can't do the job, because it executes a file in an already existing python process, so I cannot pass new arguments to it.

It would be excellent if there were just a variable for this (e.g. `python-args-for-script`), which I could set at the end of my python script via the emacs file variable mechanism.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Emacs: pass arguments to inferior Python shell during buffer evaluation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2905575/emacs-pass-arguments-to-inferior-python-shell-during-buffer-evaluation)

Comment: I, the question asker, agree, [Emacs: pass arguments...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2905575/emacs-pass-arguments-to-inferior-python-shell-during-buffer-evaluation) answers the question well enough. - Sorry that I missed it when researching...

Answer (score 1):

In the Python code, append the desired arguments you need to the `sys.argv` list before calling `python-send-buffer`.

Comment: That doesn't do the job of testing the script *as is*: I then have to change the script before I use it one the command line, which is unnecessarily error-prone. I'll edit my question to clarify.

Comment: The answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2905575/emacs-pass-arguments-to-inferior-python-shell-during-buffer-evaluation?rq=1) probably does what you want.